# Unable to set 2560x1440 ubuntu, monitor is 4k capable, GPU is 7680x4320@60Hz capable

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution

I'm struggling with resolution issue 3 days and can't do anything about it

So I have 2 monitors, one is 4k 3840x2160 and another is 1920x1080 fullHD, my GPU is capable of "7680x4320@60Hz" so it fits requirements , I can run system at 4k + fullhd without problems.
problem starts when I want to go 2560x1440.

Some strange things:

on fedora 33 I was able to run 2560x1440 with nvidia drivers working couple months with no problem, but I had to migrate to ubuntu, in ubuntu nightmare starts after installing nvidia drivers.

groovy gorilla is unable to show 2560x1440 even without nvidia drivers,it is 4k and then jumps to 1920x1080 directly, but with hippo I had 2k res without nvidia drivers, but after installing nvidia drivers (tried almost all driver versions) resolution goes away from monitor settings utility

In all above cases 2560x1440 still remains/presented in nvidias xserver tab but it is called "2560x1440 scaled" and if I'm changing res from xserver, linux becomes unresponsive freeze and crashes.

I also tried to add lines from xrandr utility, manually add resolution and got this on all ubuntus:
sudo xrandr --addmode DP-0  2560x1440_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  37
Current serial number in output stream:  38

I didn't change any cables or hardwares, tried almost everything I could do.. nothing helps here. I need to have 2560x1440 for work , like I had it with fedora 33.
I contacted devs and submitted a bug, they told me something about kernel differences and in other words they have no idea what might be an issue, HELP!!!

I dont want to change linux distro only because of that 2560x1440 resolution issue.

Comment: They did not say they had no idea that is you. What they told you is different kernels can have different video hardware support. You have not said what kernel you are running.

Comment: David, In fedora 33 always works fine , on ubuntu regardles of kernel version it not work .. and how to understand that? they told me it is kernel to blame , im saying ubuntu has issue because archlinux is ok and fedora is ok , various ubuntu kernels are not ok ... what else can I say. i tried fossa , i tried gorilla , i tried hippo, 5.4 , 5.8 , 5.11 kernels if i remember numbers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You have to add the resolution manually. I solved it this way.

With these commands you will get the possible 'Modelines' settings, which are used to add a new resolution.

```
sudo get-edid > ~/lg_edid
parse-edid < ~/lg_edid
```

You will get sth like that:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LF27T850"
    ModelName "LF27T850"
    VendorName "SAM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 22 of 2020
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 600 340
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 27-112
    VertRefresh 48-72
    # Maximum pixel clock is 300MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 291.75 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1490 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 148.50 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 74.25 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 7"
EndSection
```

In my case I am interested in a Modeline named:'Mode 0' because it contains the 2560x1440 resolution I am interested in.

```
"Mode 0" 291.75 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1490 +hsync -vsync
```

"Mode 0" is a name that you can change to whatever name you want in subsequent steps. I change it to "2560x1440".

Now you have to add the settings using `xrandr`.
First, you check what output you are interested in. You use the `xrandr` command simply by typing it in the terminal.
In my case I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1440     71.99*
```

I am interested in HDMI-2 output.

Now we need to add our Modeline:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440" 291.75 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1490 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 2560x1440
```

And that's it. There should be an option in the display settings to select a resolution.

However, these settings are not permanent. To make them permanent you have to modify the `~/.profile` file by adding two lines of code to it.

This will open the file you are interested in:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

And these two lines you paste into a file and everything will work.

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440" 291.75 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1490 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 2560x1440
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, thank you for response.
Well I did some research here and found some interesting things:

1. I'm using DisplayPort which is labeled as DP-0 in nvidias menu

looks like edid 1.3 can't recognize Display port or I'm doing something wrong ?
it says:

```
> This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun. Attempting to
> use i2c interface No EDID on bus 0 No EDID on bus 1 No EDID on bus 2
> No EDID on bus 3 Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
```

---

then I tried using HDMI instead of DPort , it was recognized by edid commands and here what I have:

```
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "LG Ultra HD"
    ModelName "LG Ultra HD"
    VendorName "GSM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 5 of 2016
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 600 340
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-135
    VertRefresh 56-61
    # Maximum pixel clock is 300MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz

#Extension block found. Parsing...
Modeline    "Mode 8" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
Modeline    "Mode 0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync 
Modeline    "Mode 1" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 4" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
Modeline    "Mode 5" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
Modeline    "Mode 6" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
Modeline    "Mode 7" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 8"
```

EndSection

there is no 2560 here, I think maybe it is because of HDMI cable is used ?
before anything is said, again, I was able to work in fedora + nvidia drivers 2560x1440 resolution no problem in this monitor(resolution was listed) and I can do that resolution on ubuntu but without nvidia drivers.

---

any possible steps here ? Or how can I make edid see my monitor while it is connected via DisplayPort DP-0 ?

P.S.
in windows also no problem it is listed as 2560x1440 always, no matter what driver and I can set my monitor to that res any time.

Comment: one more thing to mention , before getting info with edid , I was using cvt command to get resolutions and it was  giving me that (while in DP-0 port):
 
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

I tried cvt today with HDMI and it gave me strange results like 2560x60_60.00 . 
that's why I think what resolution monitor can do in that case is port dependent.

Answer (score 0):

it will not work - there are limitations in nvidia driver to support high refresh rates(resolutions) in linux. plus it doesnt make sense to use xrandr while using nvidia drivers due to nvidia metamodes.
what this blokes above do not tell to you is that they are most likely use amd gpu. for amd their recipes will work for nvidia - no
your hope is new nvidia 470 driver - maybe it will work on wayland

Comment: sanych10 , thank you for response, so I need to restore it somehow, Im using ubuntu hippo and 460 driver. Is there any chance to ger reasonable response from nvidia support forum?  Is there a real chance they will restore that 2k mode for new driver?

Comment: and by the way, if this is driver issue , why 2k works in fedora?, maybe this is wayland , i was on x11 while fedora but x11 in ubuntu still not works , that is why i blame ubuntu rather than nvidia drivers

Comment: and one more thing , ubuntu is on x11 not wayland...

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/rtx-3090-linux-samsung-g9-no-240hz-support/173660